Is it practical to extract elements from the salt remnants of Martian oceans and lakes?
Modern human civilization needs many elements to function. Our mining efforts are based on extensive logistics and the ability to transport ores from excavation sites to processing facilities over enormous distances.
For Mars, it is not practical at almost any stage of colonization, as it is impossible to settle anywhere without habitat construction and transport infrastructure, both of which require resources. There are no roads, no water transport, and no airborne transport.
Earth could supply at first, but it is so costly that it might not be worth it, as the tyranny of the rocket equation persists.
However, oceans on Earth have a lot of elements dissolved in them and, provided hypothesis about martian oceans holds, won't martian evaporite be an ultimate ore to mine?
Supporting evidence I have discovered so far:

Mars probably had no great oxidation event.


This means that there was increased metal
concentration in oceanic water and they
precipitated during evaporation, not before it.


Different compounds have different critical concentrations.


This promotes layered structure of elements in salt
remnants increasing their concentration.

P.S. I would greatly appreciate any papers and articles about this as I haven't found much. The only remotely relevant topic is brine mining for lithium and other elements here on Earth.

The problems are concentration of elements and the difficulty of establishing industrial-scale facilities to extract the elements.  For the foreseeable future, it's going to be far cheaper to ship stuff from Earth than to extract it from Mars, asteroids etc. and it will be that expense of shipping materials from Earth that prevents colonisation.

@DaveGremlin, do you think it is possible to estimate what factors define the breaking point in the mining vs shipping cost?

I think it may be difficult.  The cost of shipping will be the cost per kilo that SpaceX is going to charge when/if they get a Starship cargo service up and running.  The cost of mining will include designing industrial plant that can work in the low-pressure CO2 atmosphere of Mars and under reduced gravity.  Also, you'll need to factor in how much added automation you want to add (I think mining on Earth is quite labour-intensive), arrangement for assembly, repair and maintenance of the plant etc....

... continued... Then there's the efficiency factor; you could ship refined materials to Mars, but on-site you'd be winning ore at whatever concentration you find it and refining that.  Finally, all the mining and refining hardware needs to be shipped from Earth.  And then there are cost overruns for large projects (not just aerospace).  The book A City on Mars by the Weinersmiths mentions this other problems.

Answer: unlikely
For an ore deposit to be economically viable, the element(s) of interest need to be in high enough concentration. This usually requires some geologic process to concentrate minerals from their low background concentration. The minerals in ocean water are mostly in low, uniform concentration so deposits formed from evaporated Mars oceans would be expected to reflect this.
However, Mars has signs of past tectonic activity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tectonics_of_Mars The processes which have produced ore bodies on earth may have been operating on Mars in the past as well

Ore deposits are rock volumes containing selected elements in
sufficient concentration and quantity that they can be extracted
economically. Except for Fe and Al, all technically important metals
and other elements are scarce, in total constituting less than ~1% of
the Earth's crust. Depending on the element and its mineralogy, a 10-
to 10 000-fold enrichment is required for economic extraction today.
Such extreme element concentration involves a combination of processes
operating in concert, which explains why ore deposits have similar
characteristics but are relatively rare.
Selective element enrichment generally includes steps of


(1)dissolution of elements from common crustal or mantle rocks,


(2)physical transport by a mobile phase such as a melt or an aqueous
fluid, and


(3) chemical precipitation in distinct minerals forming the
ore deposit.
Element transport by hydrothermal fluid (a water-rich agent that can
flow through permeable and commonly fractured rocks) is particularly
efficient and chemically selective.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/ore-deposit

My concern with ore bodies is that even if they do exist, are rich and are distributed similarly to those on Earth it is still not enough for successful colonisation. Long range transportation is almost impossible on mars and thus only small areas around initial settlements are available. Moreover, they are available only for those settlements that are near, not for the others.

On Earth, salt deposits are not used for mining anything but salt. It is unlikely to be different on Mars. Mining low concentration ore is very resource intensive. It is usually less resource intensive to mine high concentrations, then move the product. "Why do you keep robbing banks?" "Well, your honor, that's where the money is."

In the US, lithium is recovered from brine pools in Nevada. "not anything but salt" seems to be wrong. "Chile is the leading producer, followed by Argentina. Both countries recover lithium from brine pools." from wikipedia

@Uwe ... true, but Li+ is a chloride salt, like NaCl.

But isn't it the purpose then? If you mean salt as any compound similar to NaCl, there are may elements the could be mined. Currently, brine mining wiki lists quite a few that are mined today: calcium, iodine, lithium, magnesium, potassium and bromine. If other sources are unavailable, then other elements become feasible. As I understand, even uranium could be mined this way.

Long ago, when there was very little free oxygen in the atmosphere of Earth, iron was dissolved in the oceans. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banded_iron_formation
